# NA coefficients produced by clogit model

Tags: r, logistic, clogit

I am trying to run a conditional logistic regression using `clogit()` from the `survival` package. The binary response variable is subject disease status and the main predictor of interest is a score between 1 and 5. However, when I add extra co-variates that are factors to the model, their coefficients are always `NA`. This problem does not occur with co-variates that are continuous and numeric and the model runs properly.

Other answers I have found suggest that the reason for this is singularity (the linear dependence of the co-variate upon another variable). However, I only have the binary response, the predictor of interest and the case-control match in `strata()`, none of which seem related to the problematic factors.

Also, other answers relate to other functions such as `lm` and `glm`. I can't find any mention of this problem with `clogit`.

Here is the output when I include participant sex (factor) in the model.

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(rep(1, 959L), ST) ~ WCR + 
    Sex + strata(Pair), data = dat, method = "exact")

  n= 959, number of events= 480 

               coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)   
WCR        -0.23490   0.79065  0.07411 -3.17  0.00153 **
Sex2             NA        NA  0.00000    NA       NA   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

           exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
WCR           0.7906      1.265    0.6838    0.9142
Sex2              NA         NA        NA        NA

Rsquare= 0.011   (max possible= 0.489 )
Likelihood ratio test= 10.35  on 1 df,   p=0.001
Wald test            = 10.05  on 1 df,   p=0.002
Score (logrank) test = 10.25  on 1 df,   p=0.001
```

Apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: In your matched sets have you by design or chance only got people of the same sex in each matched set?

Comment: I think you are right - all the co-variates I am trying are already matched by design and therefore do not need adjustment. I was indeed missing something obvious. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: I think you can look at the interaction of Sex with Wcrf_C_Cal if that corresponds to a hypothesis of clinical interest.

Comment: How did you solve this problem? I have met the same problem.Thanks!

Comment: I was including in the model a co-variate that was already matched by the study design and it needed to be removed. (By the way you should delete this as it's not an answer, better to leave a comment instead.)